# How to link an Amazon EC2 instance of a jupyter notebook to a Namecheap subdomain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, subdomain, jupyter-notebook, namecheap

I need some help linking a newly created Amazon EC2 instance to a Namecheap subdomain. For the purposes of this question, we'll say my website is called example.com. Currently, example.com is linked to a Github Page (I've added two A records and a CNAME record per these [instructions](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9645/2208/how-do-i-link-my-domain-to-github-pages)). I now want to create a subdomain called notebook.example.com, which should point to my EC2 instance that is exposing a Jupyter Notebook (which I created per these [instructions](https://chrisalbon.com/jupyter/run_project_jupyter_on_amazon_ec2.html)). So far, I've:

- Created an Elastic IP Address and assigned it to the EC2 instance (let's say it is 55.101.38.114).
- In Route 53, I created a Hosted Zone (none existed) and created a Record Set with name="notebook" of type A and the value=55.101.38.114.

This is where I'm stuck. On Namecheap, I created a URL Redirect Record with Host=notebook and value=https://55.101.38.114:8888/ with masking, but when I type https://notebook.example.com, it hangs up on "Connecting ..." and ultimately says "This site cannot be reached." Where did I go wrong?

**EDIT**:

I've almost answered by own question by connecting to http://notebook.example.com instead of https://notebook.example.com. Also, I am able to connect if I turn off masking. **Is there any way I can still connect with masking?** I'd like to see the jupyter notebook at notebook.example.com rather than it redirecting to https://55.101.38.114:8888/.

**EDIT #2**:

**Route53 setup**

[image: Route53]

**Namecheap setup** (I removed the URL Redirect)

[image: Namecheap]

Comment: Okay, so your domain is managed by Namecheap. Have you configured your Namecheap *Nameservers* to point to Route 53? Where did you configured the CNAME record -- was it in Namecheap or in Route 53?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have not configured by Namecheap nameservers to point to Route 53. Currently I use Namecheap BasicDNS. If I point my namecheap nameservers to Route 53, will that break my link to my Github page? I've added screenshots for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add NS records for the nameservers from Route 53 in Namecheap. I also added an A record in Namecheap with the EC2 instance's elastic IP. I still have to specify the port to connect (notebook.example.com:8888).

This is what Namecheap should look like:

[image: namecheap final]

Thanks to @JohnRotenstein.